# Javascript cut text after key word

Tags: javascript, replace

I have text with converted html and line breaks and tabs and any other symbols like:

```
…
          &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
      {/block:Faver}
          &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
some so bad text
what i need to cut
```

I need to cut with javascript (or jquery, if need) all text after keyword:

```
&lt;/html&gt;
```

Have any ideas or examples?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I wish more responders would read that too, to help enforce that practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression. Usually, you'd need the 'm' modifier, for multiline, and the 's' modifier, for dotall. Reference here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

However, the dotall modifier does not exist in javascript, so I usually go for a character class "[\x00-\xff]". This regexp replace should do the trick:

```
resultString = yourInputString.replace(/(&lt;\/html&gT;)[\x00-\xff]*/m, "$1");
```

Comment: You are probably forgetting to escape the slash. This code works on my javascript console: "important text\n&lt;/html&gt;\nsome so bad text\nwhat i need to cut".replace(/(\/html&gt;)[\x00-\xff]*/m, "$1");

Comment: hmm, works normal this thing html = html.replace(/(<\/html>)[\x00-\xff]*/mi, "$1");

Answer (score 3):

```
myStringThatContainsStuffToCut.split("&lt;/html&gt;")[1];
```

Comment: I think you should use `str = str.split("&lt;/html&gt;")[0] + '&lt;/html&gt;'` because he want to cut of the text after this key, in other words he only want the text before this.

Comment: But he still wants that string, so you should also add it back to the end of `[0]`

Comment: Split doesn't remove stuff, @vol7ron. I don't know Wouter, that doesn't sound right...

Comment: Elliot: yes it does. Whatever text you're splitting on is considered the delimiter and won't be returned in the resulting array.  @Wouter J: you must have edited your comment :)

Comment: Thanx for help! Solution text = text.split("</html>")[0] + '</html>';